# i have problem to insert value in a table in database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

this is my code

```
private void jButtonOKActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
{
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    try {
        Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
       Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oop", "root", "");
       System.out.println("Database successfully connected! Proof: " +con.toString());

       int column = 0;
       int row = table.getSelectedRow();
       String value = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString();

       System.out.println(value);

       Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
       String query1 = "select * from package where packageID='"+value+"'";
      ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query1);

      while(rs.next()) {
          String packageID = rs.getString("packageID");
          String packageName = rs.getString("packageName");
          String location = rs.getString("locationPackage");
          String noPeoplePackage = rs.getString("noPeoplePackage");
          String datePackage = rs.getString("datePackage");
          String pricePackage = rs.getString("pricePackage");

          String query2 = ("insert into booking(locationBooking, noBookingPeople, dateBooking)+ values ('"+location+"','"+noPeoplePackage+"','"+datePackage+"')") ;
          int rss=stmt.executeUpdate(query2);
         //model.addRow(new Object[] {packageID, packageName,location,noPeoplePackage,datePackage,pricePackage});
      }




       // rs.close();
        //stmt.close();
        //con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

it is supposed to take the value from the field to insert in the database. however, this is the output
"You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB for the right syntaax use near '+values("Langkawi Island","5", "31/12/2019")'"

Comment: Remove the `+` before `VALUES`, as it does not belong there. Then, read about using prepared statements with your Node.js code, which will prevent many other problems you still might have.

Comment: after i removed the + i got another error which is operation not allowed after ResultSet Closed. how can i overcome this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
"insert into booking values ("+location+","+noPeoplePackage+","+datePackage)";
```

Comment: An answer that starts with "Try" and doesn't go on to explain why that should be tried, or what effect is being sought is more of a comment. Explain why you think that will fix the problem and how it will fix the problem.

Comment: see there can be many solutions to one problem and i'm giving one of those that's why i told the word try this

Answer (score 0):

remove + before values() and no need to use single quotes in query

Comment: after i removed the + i got another error which is operation not allowed after ResultSet Closed. how can i overcome this